# error list indices must be integers or slices, not str in flask

Tags: python, list, dictionary, flask, random

when I want to check the answers of a random question, flask debugger shows the error: `list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request, redirect, url_for
import random

app = Flask(__name__)
data = [{'q':'question text 1', 'ans':'a1', 'idsh':101}, {'q':'question text 2', 'ans':'a2', 'idsh':102}, {'q':'question text 3', 'ans':'a3', 'idsh':103}, {'q':'question text 4', 'ans':'a4', 'idsh':104}, ]

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html', data = random.choice(data))


@app.route('/anss')
def answerd():
    if request.args.get('ans') == data['ans']:
        return "yes"
    else:
        return "no"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [{'q':'question text 1', 'ans':'a1', 'idsh':101}, ...]
```

creates a list. Lists can only be accessed by their indices. You have created a list that contains dictionaries. So, `data[0]` would point to `{'q':'question text 1', 'ans':'a1', 'idsh':101}`. You could get the answer with `data[0]['ans']`.

The route `answerd()` does not know for what question it should validate the answer.

You can either loop through all the dicts within your list and check if `data[i]['idsh'] == request.args.get('idsh')` or you need to store your data differently, for example like this (assuming `idsh` is the unique question id):

`data = {101: 'a1', ...}`

Then you can check for the correct answer like this:

```
if request.args.get('ans') == data[request.args.get('idsh')]:
```

Note that you should check if the arguments are valid before using them like this.

Comment: as you can see this is a web game that choosing the random number for showing the random question from ```data``` and I solve this problem with your help but now I can't define value to another function like ```answerd```. can you help me again :)

Comment: @Hamedmvd I made a mistake in my answer and corrected it. `data = {101: 'a1', ...}` stores just the answers to your ids. If you want to store your entire dicts, you need to compare to the `ans`-key, otherwise you can handle it as shown above. If you have another question, feel free to post a new question. I check `flask`-tag regularly.